# Apache2 + mod_ruby - how to handle all requests with one script?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby

I was about writing my own HTTP Server. Well I did, but conerning security issues it was too time expensive doing it on and I drove back having a unique solution with Apache2 and Mod_Ruby in-between.

Now I have a single Ruby Script, launching other scripts. I want that single Ruby Script to be the only script accessed by Apache each request:

`domain.com/path/to?arguments=value`

will be sent to my script `test.rbx`, whatever will be entered.

How can I do this?

Actually I can only access the `test.rbx` itself. From there I can call `Apache::Request.unparsed_uri`, which would receive the complete path with parameters. But only by accessing `domain.com/test.rbx` - how to call `domain.com/test.rbx` for every request implicitly?

Joern.